# Comparing two dictionaries and adding dictionary value to another dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, comparison

I am trying to compare two dictionaries loaded in. Each individual contains an ID and an Individual object.

The code so far is

```
            _Individuals1 = file1.fileIndividuals;
        _Individuals2 = file2.fileIndividuals;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Individual> kvpInd in _Individuals1)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Individual> kvpInd2 in _Individuals2)
            {
                if (kvpInd.Value.name.name == kvpInd2.Value.name.name)
                {
                    similarInds.Add(kvpInd.Key, kvpInd.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

and im getting the error of "An item with the same key has already been added."
I can kind of see why but im not sure how to go about it differently to make it work. Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Comment: What is _supposed_ to happen when `name.name` has multiple hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple entries with the same value in a dictionary. You are doing nothing to check or compare the keys.

So, you have multiple entries in _Individuals2 with the same value though they have different keys.

I don't know what you are doing here, but I would think that your keys should be what makes each object unique and they should really not be comparing the values. If you use a list or something like that you can just use the Intersection method to return what they have in common.

Or you could just use

```
_Individuals1.Values.Intersect(_Individuals2.Values);
```

Also, when playing around with generics, it almost always pays off to override the equality operators of the objects being stored in the generic. Then you don't have to do things like:

```
if (kvpInd.Value.name.name == kvpInd2.Value.name.name)
```

Comment: it seems that the intersect method seems to work the best :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've got a bad assumption about the relationship between keys and values in different `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instances.  It's very possible for multiple entries to have different keys but the same value.  If that ever happens in `_Individuals2` then you'll end up adding the same key to the dictionary twice.  Consider

Map1

- Key 1, Value Dog

Map2

- Key 2, Value Dog
- Key 3, Value Dog

In this scenario multiple values in Map2 have the value Dog.  So I'd end up essentially executing the following based on your algorithm

```
// 1:Dog matches 2:Dog
similarInds.Add(1, "Dog");
// 1:Dog matches 3:Dog
similarInds.Add(1, "Dog");
```

It seems like what you want here is to simply know the set of `Individual` objects which are similar between the two maps.  If so then just store the value and use a `Set<Individual>` to prevent duplicates.

```
var similarInds = new HashSet<Individual>();
...

similarInds.Add(kvpInd.Value);
```

Comment: doesnt like it when I try
var similarInds = new Set<Individuals>();
apparently Set doesnt exist

Comment: @user1290653 sorry, should've been `HashSet<T>`.  Updated my answer

Comment: how do I then create that into a data source for a listbox (lstIndividuals.DataSource)

Comment: @user1290653 to put it into a list box you probably want to convert it back to a `List<T>` first via `.ToList()`

Comment: @user1290653 but what do you want the keys to be in the new dictionary?

Comment: just int i = 0 incremented by 1 for each record. Although i dont neccessarily need keys

Comment: basically, when similarInds was a dictionary, the datasource was lstIndividuals.DataSource = similarInds.Select(Individual => Individual.Value).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it with lambdas:

```
var similarInds = file1.fileIndividuals.
Where(kv1 => file2.fileIndividuals.Any(kv2 => kv1.Value.name.name == kv2.Value.name.name)).
ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back here. You have two Dictionaries that key Individuals to an integer. However, you're not comparing the keys of the relative Dictionaries, but rather their values. This makes me think that the keys are not unique.

It sounds like what you want is the full outer join of both Dictionaries:

- In cases where an Individual is present in only File1, use the Key and Value for the Individual from File1.
- Ditto for individuals only in File2.
- Where both of the files contain the same Individual (by name), merge the records.

This can be accomplished with some Linq. Understand this won't be the most performant of the possible solutions, but it's a little easier to understand what's going on.

```
//get records from 1 that aren't in 2
var left = _Individuals1.Where(l=>!_Individuals2.Any(r=>l.Value.Name == r.Value.Name));
//get records that appear in both 1 and 2, 
//using the select clause to "merge" the data you want from each side
var join = from l in _Individuals1
           join r in _Individuals2 on l.Value.Name equals r.Value.Name
           select new KeyValuePair<int, Individual>(l.Key, r.Value);
//get records from 2 that aren't in 1
var right = _Individuals2.Where(r=>!_Individuals1.Any(l=>l.Value.Name == r.Value.Name));

//Now, the keys from the left and join enumerables should be consistent,
//because we used the keys from _Individuals1 in both of them.
var merged = left.Concat(join).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);

//BUT, keys from records that only existed in 2 may have duplicate keys, 
//so don't trust them
var maxKey = merged.Keys.Max();
foreach(var r in right)
   merged.Add(++maxKey, r.Value);
```

You can avoid creating the "left" enumerable explicitly, by structuring the query that produces "join" to produce a left join instead of the inner join I show. You can also try to use keys from _Individuals2 by checking each one against the merged Directory. That code would look like this:

```
var maxKey = merged.Keys.Max();
foreach(var r in right)
   if(merged.ContainsKey(r.Key))
      merged.Add(++maxKey, r.Value);
   else
   {
      merged.Add(r.Key, r.Value);
      maxKey = r.Key > maxKey ? r.Key : maxKey;
   }
```

This will safely use keys from _Individuals2 whenever the key wouldn't be a duplicate, so some (but probably not all) keys from _Individuals2 should be used. Whether this is "better" depends on the exact situation.

Comment: there is an error on line join r in _Individuals2 on l.Value.Name == r.Value.Name :(

Comment: i dont think it likes the r.Value.name part

Comment: Edited; instead of an `==` operator you have to use the keyword `equals`. The specification of the joining criteria isn't an expression; it's defining the projections of the two enumerables which must be equal when compared. If you look at the Enumerable.Join method that is used behind the scenes that would be clearer; you're expected to provide two lambdas that return the "inner key" and "outer key".